# Manually Sort An Array with no common key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've tried many solutions here but they all seem to require a common key to sort the array by.

My var_dump() for the array is as follows:

array(10) { [0]=> string(11) "Agriculture" [2]=> string(6) "Metals" [12]=> string(10) "Sanitation" [14]=> string(19) "Health & Beauty" [22]=> string(13) "Oil & Gas" [27]=> string(12) "Construction" [31]=> string(13) "Manufacturing" [58]=> string(8) "Retailer" [61]=> string(11) "Distributor" [77]=> string(7) "Service" }

I'd like to be able to sort the strings in the array into the following order:

- Service
- Distributor
- Retailer
- Manufacturing
- Construction
- Oil & Gas
- Health & Beauty
- Sanitation
- Metals
- Agriculture

I know this is not an ideal solution but I really need to manually sort these.

Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the array contain anything else? Are the indices meaningful? What's the difference between sorting this array according to your arbitrary order vs. just doing `$newArray = array('Service', 'Distributor', ...);`? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: The main difference is that this one is generated from a database, so removing one from the databases should also remove it from the array. Hence why I can't manually create it.

Comment: What happens if a new entry is _added to_ the database? Since the sorting heuristic applies to a closed set of values we don't know where to put the new one. Can the sort order come from the database too?

Comment: You should consider storing the sort order as a numeric information in your database, and then perform the query with the suitable `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main difference is that this one is generated from a database, so removing one from the databases should also remove it from the array. Hence why I can't manually create it.

So, I assume, that if one is added to the database, it should somehow also be "available"?
If one is renamed in the Database, sorting should still work?

The only reliable solution would be to add another column to the database table, let's call it `position` - and then fetch the entries and sort them by the position value, which could be 1 upto 10.

Hint on that: Start with a step size of thausand (1000,2000,3000,...) This allows you to add an item later somewhere in between without changing all subsequent item as well. (i.e. creating an entry with position 1500 would become the new second entry, and everything else will automatically shift one position down. If another "new second entry" shall be inserted, you can use 1250 and so on... Gives you some "time" until you have to finally reindex the positions - Use decimal/double if you want to keep this going forever^^)

Comment: I suspect that you have used this approach before.  Nice answer.

Comment: @RyanVincent Since 15 years for about every "Pre-Sorted-Database-List" that changes rarely. (If positions are modified through an application UI, there is no problem in gap-less positions ofc, altering subsequent items would be a single update statement: `UPDATE table SET position=position+1 WHERE positon >= PositionToBeInserted`) - But writing an ui for 10 different Salutations / Menu Entries that change about never is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like you want to sort you array by index in descending order. For that you should use `krsort()` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php

Comment: Looks like that to me too

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array in a reverse order use

```
array array_reverse ( array $array [, bool $preserve_keys = FALSE ]
```

Parameters

array
The input array.

preserve_keys
If set to TRUE numeric keys are preserved. Non-numeric keys are not affected by this setting and will always be preserved.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php